# android opengl es 2 display after several rotate error

Tags: android, arraylist, opengl-es, rotation

I am trying to draw lines connected to each other. Let's say they are creating a
rectangle. At each corner also I have points. When I have tested code in my 
Samsung Galaxy Note 4 after several rotations, using touch, all rectangle ended up
with a single point at the center. I could not figure out why this was happening. 
Code works fine in emulator. Also I am storing line and point data as array list 
in my code. These array lists are used to create line and point object classes to 
render.

```
public class GLRender implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] mVRMatrix = new float[16];
private static ArrayList<Line> DrLine = new ArrayList<Line>();
private static ArrayList<Point> DrPoint = new ArrayList<Point>();
private float ratio;
private float Joint1;
private float Joint2;
private float x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2;
private float px, py, pz, ps;
private float[] nearN = new float[4];

private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> LineArray =  new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
private ArrayList<String> L = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> P = new ArrayList<String>();
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> PointArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
private static ArrayList<String> EmptyLine = new ArrayList<String>();
private static ArrayList<String> EmptyPoint = new ArrayList<String>();
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> UndoL = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>();
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> UndoP = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>();

public GLRender(Activity activity) {
}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
    // Set the background frame color
    //GLES20.glClearColor(0.53f, 0.53f, 0.53f, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.474f, 0.537f, 0.078f, 1.0f);
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    Drawer();

    Line XLine = new Line();
    XLine.SetVerts(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f / 10, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    XLine.SetColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    Line YLine = new Line();
    YLine.SetVerts(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f / 10, 0.0f);
    YLine.SetColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    Line ZLine = new Line();
    ZLine.SetVerts(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f / 10);
    ZLine.SetColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mViewMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 1.0f , 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mRotationMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, mXAngle, 0, 1f, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, mYAngle, 1f, 0, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mVRMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mVRMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mMVPMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mVRMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.scaleM(mMVPMatrix,0,mScale,mScale,mScale);

    if (DrLine.size() > 0) {
        for (Line LineX : DrLine) {
            LineX.draw(mMVPMatrix);
        }
    }

    if (DrPoint.size() > 0) {
        for (Point PointX : DrPoint) {
            PointX.draw(mMVPMatrix);
        }
    }

    XLine.draw(mMVPMatrix);
    YLine.draw(mMVPMatrix);
    ZLine.draw(mMVPMatrix);
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    ratio = (float) width / height;

    //Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio*10, ratio*10, -10, 10, 1, 9);
    Matrix.orthoM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1.0f, 1.0f, -5.0f, 5.0f);
}

public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

    // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

    // add the source code to the shader and compile it
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

    return shader;
}

private Float TempMaxPointHolder = 0.0f;
private Float MaxPointHolder = 0.0f;

public Float Scaler(){

    Float TempScaler = 1.0f;
    Iterator<ArrayList<String>> MaxPointFinder = PointArray.iterator();

    while (MaxPointFinder.hasNext()){
        ArrayList<String> MaxPoint = MaxPointFinder.next();
        TempMaxPointHolder = Math.abs(Math.max(Math.max(Float.parseFloat(MaxPoint.get(1)),Float.parseFloat(MaxPoint.get(2))),Float.parseFloat(MaxPoint.get(3))));

        if (TempMaxPointHolder > MaxPointHolder){
            MaxPointHolder = TempMaxPointHolder;
        }
    }

    TempScaler = 0.9f / MaxPointHolder;
    return TempScaler;
}

public void Drawer(){

    Float Scaler = Scaler();
    Integer Lindex = 0;

    ArrayList<Point> TempDrPoint = new ArrayList<Point>();
    ArrayList<Line> TempDrLine = new ArrayList<Line>();

    Iterator<ArrayList<String>> Litr = LineArray.iterator();

    while (Litr.hasNext()) {

        L = Litr.next();

        Joint1 = Float.parseFloat(L.get(1));
        Joint2 = Float.parseFloat(L.get(2));

        Iterator<ArrayList<String>> PitrL = PointArray.iterator();

        while (PitrL.hasNext()){

            P = PitrL.next();

            if (Float.parseFloat(P.get(0)) == Joint1) {
                x1 = Float.parseFloat(P.get(1)) * Scaler;
                y1 = Float.parseFloat(P.get(2)) * Scaler;
                z1 = Float.parseFloat(P.get(3)) * Scaler;
            }

            if (Float.parseFloat(P.get(0)) == Joint2) {
                x2 = Float.parseFloat(P.get(1)) * Scaler;
                y2 = Float.parseFloat(P.get(2)) * Scaler;
                z2 = Float.parseFloat(P.get(3)) * Scaler;
            }
        }

        Line TempLine = new Line();
        TempLine.SetVerts(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2);
        if (L.get(3) == "0") {
            TempLine.SetColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        }
        else if (L.get(3) == "1"){
            TempLine.SetColor(0.66f, 0.73f, 0.21f, 1.0f);
        }

        TempDrLine.add(TempLine);
        Lindex = Lindex + 1;
    }

    setDrLine(TempDrLine);
    Integer Pindex = 0;
    Iterator<ArrayList<String>> Pitr = PointArray.iterator();

    while (Pitr.hasNext()){

        P = Pitr.next();

        px = Float.parseFloat(P.get(1)) * Scaler;
        py = Float.parseFloat(P.get(2)) * Scaler;
        pz = Float.parseFloat(P.get(3)) * Scaler;
        ps = Float.parseFloat(P.get(4));

        Point TempPoint = new Point();
        TempPoint.SetPointVerts(px, py, pz);

        if (ps == 0.0f) {
            TempPoint.SetPointColor(0.65f, 0.37f, 0.11f, 1.0f);
        }
        else if (ps == 1.0f) {
            TempPoint.SetPointColor(0.68f, 0.07f, 0.32f, 1.0f);
        }

        TempDrPoint.add(TempPoint);
        Pindex = Pindex + 1;
    }
    setDrPoint(TempDrPoint);
}

public volatile float mXAngle;
public volatile float mYAngle;

public ArrayList<Line> getDrLine() {
    return DrLine;
}

public ArrayList<Point> getDrPoint(){
    return DrPoint;
}

public void setDrLine(ArrayList<Line> XDrLine) {
    DrLine = XDrLine;
}

public void setDrPoint(ArrayList<Point> XDrPoint) {
    DrPoint = XDrPoint;
}

public float getXAngle() {
    return mXAngle;
}

public float getYAngle(){
    return mYAngle;
}

public void setAngleX(float Xangle) {
    mXAngle = Xangle;
}

public void setAngleY(float Yangle) {
    mYAngle = Yangle;
}

public volatile float mScale = 1;
public volatile float mXFocus;
public volatile float mYFocus;

public void setZoom(float scale){
    mScale = scale;
}

public void setFocus(float XFocus, float YFocus){
    mXFocus = XFocus;
    mYFocus = YFocus;
}

public float getmScale(){
    return mScale;
}

public float getmXFocus(){
    return mXFocus;
}

public float getmYFocus(){
    return mYFocus;
}

public void setLineArray(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> XLine){
    LineArray = XLine;
}

public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getLineArray(){
    return LineArray;
}

public void setUndoL(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> UndoLine){
    this.UndoL.add(new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(UndoLine));
}

public ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> getUndoL() {
    return UndoL;
}

public void setUndoP(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> UndoPoint){
    this.UndoP.add(new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(UndoPoint));
}

public ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> getUndoP() {
    return UndoP;
}

public void setPointArray(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> XPoint){
    PointArray = XPoint;
}

public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getPointArray(){
    return PointArray;
}
```

**gives error contents_sample_state: [ agr({[3 ,38]=11, [3 ,7 ,38]=28})  ]**

```
public class Line {

private FloatBuffer VertexBuffer;

private final String VertexShaderCode =
        // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
        // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +

                "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                "void main() {" +
                // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
                "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                "}";

private final String FragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                "}";

protected int GlProgram;
protected int PositionHandle;
protected int ColorHandle;
protected int MVPMatrixHandle;

// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
static float LineCoords[] = {
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
};

private final int VertexCount = LineCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
private final int VertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

// Set color with red, green, blue and alpha (opacity) values
float color[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

public Line() {
    // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            // (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
            LineCoords.length * 4);
    // use the device hardware's native byte order
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
    VertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
    VertexBuffer.put(LineCoords);
    // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
    VertexBuffer.position(0);

    int vertexShader = GLRender.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, VertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = GLRender.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, FragmentShaderCode);

    GlProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(GlProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(GlProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(GlProgram);                  // creates OpenGL ES program executables
}

public void SetVerts(float v0, float v1, float v2, float v3, float v4, float v5) {
    LineCoords[0] = v0;
    LineCoords[1] = v1;
    LineCoords[2] = v2;
    LineCoords[3] = v3;
    LineCoords[4] = v4;
    LineCoords[5] = v5;

    VertexBuffer.put(LineCoords);
    // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
    VertexBuffer.position(0);
}

public void SetColor(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha) {
    color[0] = red;
    color[1] = green;
    color[2] = blue;
    color[3] = alpha;
}

public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
    // Add program to OpenGL ES environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(GlProgram);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    PositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(GlProgram, "vPosition");

    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(PositionHandle);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(PositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            VertexStride, VertexBuffer);

    // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
    ColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(GlProgram, "vColor");

    // Set color for drawing the triangle
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(ColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    MVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(GlProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    //GLRender.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(MVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    //GLRender.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

    GLES20.glLineWidth(5);
    // Draw the triangle
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_LINES, 0, VertexCount);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(PositionHandle);
}
}

public class GLSurface extends GLSurfaceView {

//public static GLRender xRender;
ScaleGestureDetector ScaleDetect;
MainActivity mMain;
OpenGL XOPL = mMain.xOpenGL;

public GLSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context,  attrs);

    // Render the view only when there is a change in the drawing data
    //setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);

    ScaleDetect = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleDetectorListener());
}

private float mPreviousX;
private float mPreviousY;
float density = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

private static final int MAX_CLICK_DURATION = 300;
private long pressStartTime;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

            ScaleDetect.onTouchEvent(e);

            float x = e.getX();
            float y = e.getY();

            switch (e.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    if(!ScaleDetect.isInProgress()) {

                        float xMoveRange = x - mPreviousX;
                        float yMoveRange = y - mPreviousY;
                        float dx = 0.0f;
                        float dy = 0.0f;
                        float w = this.getWidth();
                        float h = this.getHeight();

                        if (Math.abs(xMoveRange) > w / 100 && Math.abs(yMoveRange) < h / 100){
                            dx = xMoveRange / density / 2.0f;
                            XOPL.xRender.setAngleX(XOPL.xRender.getXAngle() + dx);
                        }

                        if (Math.abs(xMoveRange) < w / 100 && Math.abs(yMoveRange) > h / 100){
                            dy = yMoveRange / density / 2.0f;
                            XOPL.xRender.setAngleY(XOPL.xRender.getYAngle() + dy);
                        }

                            XOPL.myGLView.requestRender();
                    }

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    pressStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    long pressDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - pressStartTime;
                    if (pressDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION) {

                        float Nx = (x - Float.parseFloat(Double.toString(this.getWidth())) * 0.5f) / (Float.parseFloat(Double.toString(this.getWidth())) * 0.5f);
                        float Ny = (y - Float.parseFloat(Double.toString(this.getHeight())) * 0.5f) / (Float.parseFloat(Double.toString(this.getHeight())) * 0.5f);
                        float Nz = 1.0f;

                        XOPL.xRender.setNCoordinate(Nx, Ny, Nz);
                        XOPL.xRender.Selection();
                        XOPL.myGLView.requestRender();
                    }
                    break;
            }

            mPreviousX = x;
            mPreviousY = y;

    return true;
}

private float sizeCoef = 1;

public class ScaleDetectorListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    float scaleFocusX = 0;
    float scaleFocusY = 0;

    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector arg0) {
        float scale = arg0.getScaleFactor() * sizeCoef;

        sizeCoef = scale;

        XOPL.xRender.setZoom(sizeCoef);
        XOPL.myGLView.requestRender();

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector arg0) {
        invalidate();

        scaleFocusX = arg0.getFocusX();
        scaleFocusY = arg0.getFocusY();

        XOPL.xRender.setFocus(scaleFocusX,scaleFocusY);

        return true;
    }

    public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector arg0) {
        scaleFocusX = 0;
        scaleFocusY = 0;

        XOPL.xRender.setFocus(scaleFocusX,scaleFocusY);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: To answer your question, we will at least need the code of how you are drawing the lines. If you are using shaders, then plz post a minimal version of the shaders. Also, if you are using gl_line_loop or gl_line_strip, try checking with gl_lines. There can be Open GLES implementation problems.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem, but watch out for things like:

> XOPL.xRender.setAngleX(XOPL.xRender.getXAngle() + dx)

... especially when using mediump precision in shaders. Generally I'd recommend changing setAngle functions to exploit rotational symmetry and wrap the value around so you get an absolute range used at the API-level of of +-Pi.

In your current code if the user keeps swiping in one direction, eventually you'll run our of bits and everything will either stop rotating (at best), or fail with infinities or NaN results (at worst).

Note using "-Pi to +Pi" is preferred to using "0 to +2Pi", because the sign-bit is free in most floating point representations so preserves more dynamic precision.

Example code:

```
public float wrapRadians(float angle) {
    // If angle is negative ensure value is higher than minus pi
    if (angle < 0) {
        while (angle < -math.PI) {
            angle += 2 * math.PI;
        }
    // Else angle is positive so ensure value is less than pi
    } else {
        while (angle > math.PI) {
            angle -= 2 * math.PI;
        }
    }

    return angle;
}

public float setXAngle(float XAngle) {
    mXAngle = wrapRadians(XAngle);
}

public float setYAngle(float YAngle) {
    mYAngle = wrapRadians(YAngle);
}
```

Comment: I could not figure out. Could you provide a sample code.